# Most efficient way to store changes on database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working on a simple todo list just to practice, using ASP NET MVC, Entity Framework 6, SQL Server 2012 Express, KnockoutJs.

I want to know what's the recommended way to insert or update the changes made to the database.

So far I've thought about:

- Add a "Changed" column to every task, and update or insert depending if it exist or not
- Insert/Update every task.
- Post the task when it is changed, not with a global "Save" button

Any suggestion is welcome.

[Todo List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9LXc.png)

Comment: You mean something like history of the changes that happens on the database?(This history can be used to revert unwanted changes? )
Or a change like the user X completed the task Y ?

Comment: Second case. A change like the user X completed the task Y.

Comment: Well, I opted to update the row when changed to avoid modifying the previous code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *Tracker-enabled-dbcontext* (created by Bilal Fazlani) that seem to meet your needs pretty well. There are some versions of this nuget that I had used some of my ASP.NET MVC applications without any problems for auditing / logging features... You might access to the latest version on [Tracker-enabled-dbcontext](http://bilal-fazlani.github.io/tracker-enabled-dbcontext/).
Hope this helps...

Comment: This weeks I have too much work to do so I can't try it right now. But checking the website, seems useful for some projects I have to do.

Comment: @FelixJuniorRamirezBello Sure. I had already used one of its previous version in my project and that was really very useful and clean by keeping only the updated cells. You will also see this after using it :)